# Use Haskell's lenses library to fmap a lens

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

In the code below, my question concerns the top-most function `someFunc` (everything below is just to provide a complete example). I use a record-syntax getter and `fmap` there. What's the lens way to implement `someFunc`?

```
import           Control.Lens
import           Data.IntMap  (IntMap)

someFunc :: Farm -> IntMap Size
someFunc farm =
  _barnSize <$> farm ^. farmBarns

data Farm = Farm
  { _farmBarns :: IntMap Barn
  }

farmBarns :: Lens' Farm (IntMap Barn)
farmBarns = lens _farmBarns (\farm barns -> farm { _farmBarns = barns } )

type Size = (Int, Int)

data Barn = Barn
  { _barnSize :: Size
  }

barnSize :: Lens' Barn Size
barnSize = lens _barnSize (\barn size -> barn { _barnSize = size } )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just replace `_barnSize` by `(^. barnSize)` or, equivalently, `view barnSize`:

```
someFunc :: Farm -> IntMap Size
someFunc farm = view barnSize <$> farm ^. farmBarns
```

For a "100% *lens*" solution, you can use the [`mapped`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Setter.html#v:mapped) setter. In this case, though, I don't think there is any real advantage in doing that.

```
someFunc :: Farm -> IntMap Size
someFunc farm = (mapped %~ view barnSize) (farm ^. farmBarns)
```

Another possible spelling involves using `to` to combine everything in a single getter. That doesn't buy you much here either, but it might be somewhat convenient if you wanted to keep working with the `IntMap` in *lens* style by chaining additional getters/folds/etc.

```
someFunc :: Farm -> IntMap Size
someFunc farm = farm ^. farmBarns . to (fmap (view barnSize))
```

There is a special purpose combinator that subsumes the `to`/`(^.)` combination above. It is called [`views`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Getter.html#v:views):

```
someFunc :: Farm -> IntMap Size
someFunc farm = views farmBarns (fmap (view barnSize)) farm
```

Comment: @ruben.moor I added a fourth possibility, though I don't think it is better than the first one either.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mapped` (or `traversed`) to 'map' over a traversable using lenses, in your case:

```
someFunc :: Farm -> IntMap Size
someFunc farm =
    farm ^. farmBarns & mapped %~ view barnSize
```

This may be a bit confusing, but here's what's happening, I'll add brackets to make it a little clearer

```
someFunc :: Farm -> IntMap Size
someFunc farm =
    (farm ^. farmBarns) & (mapped %~ (view barnSize))
```

So basically, we use `farm ^. farmBarns` to get the `IntMap Barns` from the farm, on the right hand side of `&` we construct a setter using `%~` which is the infix of `over`, however the function which `over` passes its target to is actually just focuses a the barnSize using a lens. `view barnSize :: Barn -> Size`.

Lastly we use `&` to tie it all together which is equivalent to `flip $` and takes the setter from the right hand and uses it on the result of the left hand.

Comment: `(^..)` makes this result in `[Size]`, rather than `IntMap Size`.

Comment: I've fixed the solution to use mapped.